# VHDL nested case statement for some case options

Tags: vhdl

I am new to VHDL and working with case statements, I have something like the following:

```
process(state)
begin
  case state is
    when stop =>
      a <= input;
      b <= output;
    when move =>
      a <= input_1;
      b <= output_1;
  end case;
end process;
```

where a,b,input, output,input_1 and output 1 are signals.

My issue is that I want to have a nested case in only one of the options:

for example:

```
process(state)
begin
  case state is
    when stop =>
      a <= input;  
      b <= output;
    when move =>
      a <= if c='0' then input_1 else input_2;
      b <= if c='0' then output_1 else output_2;
  end case;
end process;
```

My question is can i do something like above where not all case options are nested but only some of them are or is there any other way in such situation , i tried using when else but got an error, saying that such syntax is not supported.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here:

> can i do something like above where not all case options are nested but only some of them are or is there any other way in such situation

but is this what you are trying to do? (Note that I've added `c` to the sensitivity list):

```
process(state,c)
begin
  case state is
    when stop =>
      a <= input;  
      b <= output;
    when move =>
      case c is
        when '0' =>
           a <= input_1;
           b <= output_1;
        when '1' =>
           a <= input_2;
           b <= output_2;
        when others => null;
  end case;
end process;
```

Comment: So, with that could it be possible to implemment hierarchical FSMs? Would the synthesizer recognize this?

Comment: What do you mean by recognise?  The synthesiser will produce logic that matches your description and therefore will be functionally correct (if not, file a bug :).  Whether it produces an "optimal" representation will depend on the synthesiser and what you call "optimal" vs. the tuning flags passed to the tool

Comment: For example, XST recognize that it is a FSM an optimize for that. My question is if there are a FSM inside another the synthesizer will optimize the two. I made a little test with XST, and recognize me only the lower one. However the top FSM was very simple...

Comment: @ferdepe I'm not surprised that xst doesn't see nested state machines. I don't know if any synthesisers would actually . But does than logic meet timing ? And does it meet your resource target? And is the code readable? Those are the key measurements to begin with imho.

Comment: The code is readable, and for the moment meet my resource target... I have to see my meeting requirements. I'm using it in lower frequencies...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fraught with perils.  Assigning an output to an internal signal can require an output port mode of inout or buffer or VHDL 2008 support which isn't universal for synthesis.  Generally mode buffer isn't supported either.

To get to the heart of your question sequential signal assignments supporting when else are supported in VHDL 2008 but not generally in synthesis.

A case statement choice contains sequential statements.

You can use an if statement instead:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity foo is
    port (
        signal input:       in      std_logic;
        signal output:      inout   std_logic;
        signal input_1:     in      std_logic;
        signal input_2:     in      std_logic;
        signal output_1:    inout   std_logic;
        signal output_2:    inout   std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    signal a, b:    std_logic;
    signal c:       std_logic;
    type some_state is (stop, move);
    signal state: some_state;
begin
UNLABELED:
    process(state)
    begin
    case state is
        when stop =>
            a <= input;
            b <= output;
        when move =>
            if c = '0' then
                a <= input_1;
                b <= output_1;
            else 
                a <= input_2;
                b <= output_2;
            end if;
        end case;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Notice your two evaluations of `c` have been collapsed into one.

Besides the conditional signal assignment states that are supported as sequential statements in VHDL 2008, there's also selected signal assignment statements (likewise generally not supported by synthesis as sequential statements).

Answer (score 0):

VHDL before 2008 does not have a ternary operator (C-like `? :`) for sequential
statements, so you can't write `if c='0' then input_1 else input_2`, but in
VHDL-2008 you can write `input_1 when c='0' else input_2`.

However, the compact coding style can be achieved by making a small function:

```
function ternary(cond : boolean; res_true, res_false : std_logic) return std_logic is
begin
  if cond then
    return res_true;
  else
    return res_false;
  end if;
end function;
```

Whereby the move part of the code can be written like:

```
when move =>
  a <= ternary(c='0', input_1, input_2);
  b <= ternary(c='0', output_1, output_2);
```

You can also make a nested case like:

```
when move =>
  case c is
    when '0' =>
      a <= input_1;
      b <= output_1;
    when others  =>
      a <= input_2;
      b <= output_2;
  end case;
```

Or do it with `if then else` as David showed.